# long accelerometer data divided by short one to perform fft in matlab

Tags: matlab, fft, accelerometer

I recorded with an accelerometer for 2 hours (it's sampling rate is 100Hz). To analyze the data, I want to perform fft. I think the whole data is so long, so I want to divide it by 10sec or 5sec. Is it possible?

now, I have data (1479168x1 ; one of x,y,z) with 100Hz sample rate. I want to analyze it divided by 5secs time window. (512x2889). Then, Is it right to perform fft with 512 samples (as one frame sample , total 2889 frames)?        Below is my code

```
no_point = 512; %% for 5seconds data of 10ms data point
Fs=100; %% sample rate
acc = data;
no_frame = length(data)/no_point;    
frame_data = reshape(acc, no_point, no_frame)';
f = hann(no_point);
hann_window = repmat(f',no_frame,1);
fspace = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,no_point/2+1);

fp = zeros(no_frame, no_point);
for iframe = 1:no_frame
    mean_data = mean(frame_data(iframe,:));
    std_data = std(frame_data(iframe,:));
    fp(iframe,:) = (frame_data(iframe,:)-mean_data)*100/mean_data;
end

fp_hann = hann_window.*fp;

abs_fp = zeros(no_frame, no_point/2+1);
for iframe = 1:no_frame
    Y = fft(fp_hann(iframe,:),no_point);
    abs_fp(iframe,:) = 2*abs(Y(1:no_point/2+1));
end
```

Comment: FFT has a time complexity of O(n *log(n)) so I doubt it is going to take much longer, if it even does take longer at all.

Comment: Change the sample rate
https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html

Comment: Thank you for your answers, guys but, I don't get it. Can you tell me more detail?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you want to analyze. I think you have to read about [Short-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform/)

There are a lot of information about  STFT. See for example free book - [SPECTRAL AUDIO SIGNAL PROCESSING](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/STFT_Time_Frequency_Distribution.html)

Matlab has special function [Spectrogram using short-time Fourier transform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) in Signal Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

> I recorded with an accelerometer for 2 hours (it's sampling rate is 100Hz). To analyze the data, I want to perform fft. I think the whole data is so long, so I want to divide it by 10sec or 5sec. Is it possible?

In order to answer this part you have to understand that the resolution of FFT depends on the time of observation, so in your case you are dividing the complete reading into window of time. This effect will degrades the resolution. 
Also you will miss some frequencies if they are not present in the window you performed. Also the sideloobes will be very high due to sudden clipping.

If resolution is not important for your case, the answer is yes you can do it and perform FFT on portion but with worst resolution and all the above mentioned problem.